# e.preventDefault() not working, but event data is correct

Tags: javascript

I have event listeners applied to two elements which react to a mousedown event. They work fine, but it causes the right click menu to appear which i am trying to prevent.

I am not fully understanding why it is not working. This is my code:

```
function moveDiv(e){    
    e.preventDefault();    //not working

    if(e.button == 2){     //works on right click only, so e is correct data
        console.log(this); //works - shows element data
    }
}

function load(){    

    function addEvents(){           
        var d = getDiv('overview'); //getDiv gets the element by id
            d.addEventListener('mousedown',moveDiv,false);
        var d = getDiv('login_data');
            d.addEventListener('mousedown',moveDiv,false);
    }

    templateLoad('main.html',addEvents); //works: async loads page, then call function 'addEvents'  
}

load();
```

I have added comments to show which lines are working, which i tested using console.log. `e` is correct given `e.button` responds only on right click, so i don't know why `e.preventDefault()` fails to work in this case.

Comment: What browser? Have you tried `e.stopPropagation()` ?

Comment: Probably because it's not the *mousedown* event that triggers the context menu. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/contextmenu

Comment: @RosdiKasim I don't see how that would help

Comment: @Phil so does that mean i have to use a different trigger event other than `mousedown` to prevent it ? What would you suggest?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add an event listener for the [*contextmenu*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/contextmenu) event, eg

```
.addEventListener('contextmenu', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
}, false);
```

<kbd>[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nn88eemf/)</kbd>